# PHP/MYSQL utf8 file open syntax error, but works fine via phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

environment specs:

```
os:windows 7 64 bit
webserver:wamp(apache) with:
                    php 5.3.8
                    mysql 5.5.16
text editor in use:notepad++
```

problem:
Trying to load a .sql file consisting of data which has utf8 (hebrew) data in it,
the syntax **is correct according to phpmyadmin**, however when trying to upload the file via a php script it outputs an error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS squazza; CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS squazza; ' at line 1
```

the sql file(db/default.sql) is:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS squazza;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS squazza;

use squazza;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mainframe` (
  `storedbottles` smallint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bottlescompressed` smallint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `users` smallint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accessname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pagename` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `metadesc` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `metakey` varchar(180) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leftcontent` longtext,
  `rightcontent` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identification` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `born` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `joined` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paypal` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` float(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bottles` smallint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `administrator` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
INSERT INTO `pages` (`accessname`,`pagename`, `title`, `metadesc`, `metakey`, `lang`, `leftcontent`, `rightcontent`) VALUES
('register','הרשמה', 'הסבר מפורט אלינו', 'הסבר אל יוצריומפתחי הדחסן הבקבוקים', 'בקבוקים,דחסן,בקבוק,איכות הסביבה', 'he','<h2>הרשמה</h2><br\><h4>דף הרשמה למשטמשים חדשים</h4><br\>','<h3>דף זה הוא הינו דף הרשמה למשטמשים חדשים המעוניינים להיצתרף לשרות דחיסת הבקבוקים.');
INSERT INTO `pages` (`accessname`,`pagename`, `title`, `metadesc`, `metakey`, `lang`, `leftcontent`, `rightcontent`) VALUES
('login','כניסה', 'הסבר מפורט אלינו', 'הסבר אל יוצריומפתחי הדחסן הבקבוקים', 'בקבוקים,דחסן,בקבוק,איכות הסביבה', 'he','<h2>משחזר הבקבוקים</h2><br\><h4>רק שחזור מוביל לשיפור</h4><br\>','<h3>פרויקט דחסן</h3>פרויקט דחסן הוא הינו פרויקט שנועד לשפר את איכות הסביבה');
INSERT INTO `pages` (`accessname`,`pagename`, `title`, `metadesc`, `metakey`, `lang`, `leftcontent`, `rightcontent`) VALUES
('aboutproject','אל הפרויקט', 'הסבר מפורט אלינו', 'הסבר אל יוצריומפתחי הדחסן הבקבוקים', 'בקבוקים,דחסן,בקבוק,איכות הסביבה', 'he','<h2>משחזר הבקבוקים</h2><br\><h4>רק שחזור מוביל לשיפור</h4><br\>','<h3>פרויקט דחסן</h3>פרויקט דחסן הוא הינו פרויקט שנועד לשפר את איכות הסביבה');
INSERT INTO `pages` (`accessname`,`pagename`, `title`, `metadesc`, `metakey`, `lang`, `leftcontent`, `rightcontent`) VALUES
('aboutus','אלינו', 'הסבר מפורט אלינו', 'הסבר אל יוצריומפתחי הדחסן הבקבוקים', 'בקבוקים,דחסן,בקבוק,איכות הסביבה', 'he','<h2>משחזר הבקבוקים</h2><br\><h4>רק שחזור מוביל לשיפור</h4><br\>','<h3>פרויקט דחסן</h3>פרויקט דחסן הוא הינו פרויקט שנועד לשפר את איכות הסביבה');
INSERT INTO `pages` (`accessname`,`pagename`, `title`, `metadesc`, `metakey`, `lang`, `leftcontent`, `rightcontent`) VALUES
('home','בית', 'דף בית של הדחסן', 'הדחסן שדוחס בקבוקים וסם כסף ברטיס אוטומתי', 'בקבוקים,דחסן,בקבוק,איכות הסביבה', 'he','<h2>משחזר הבקבוקים</h2><br\><h4>רק שחזור מוביל לשיפור</h4><br\>','<h3>פרויקט דחסן</h3>פרויקט דחסן הוא הינו פרויקט שנועד לשפר את איכות הסביבה');
```

and the PHP code which is trying to submit the file is:

```
$link=new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS) or die('Could not connect to database');

        mysqli_multi_query($link,file_get_contents('db/default.sql')) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

now there are several things which solved the sql error but made new problems such as setting the encoding of the file(in notepade++) to UTF- WITHOUT BOM
 such as garble hebrew text thus I have to keep the file as utf8.

Comment: Removing the BOM *is* the solution and it won't garble anything. It's only that you need to ensure that the file is opened as UTF-8.

Comment: Please read completley, BOM is not the problem here.

Comment: I have a similar process and found it buggy when trying to drop and create the database in the .sql text file.  Once I moved DROP and CREATE DATABASE to the PHP script the process worked fine.  Also, I recall that not having extra lines between commands helped too.

Comment: Just tried removing CREATE and DROP but there is a new error now 'use squazza; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mainframe` ( `storedbottles` ' at line 1

Comment: Right, you would remove the USE also.  Because your connection is already made to squazza.  Then your code block should look like this: `$query = "USE squazza;";  $query .= file_get_contents('db/default.sql');$result=$mysqli->multi_query('$query');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is a Unicode character used to signal the endianness (byte order) of a text file or stream. In a UTF-8 file is a three byte sequence (`0xEF`,`0xBB`,`0xBF`) and it doesn't really serve that purpose because the UTF-8 encoding does not support different byte orders. It can be used by text editors and other tools to detect that a file is encoded as UTF-8 but most of the times it will just get injected on top of the actual file contents, which is the issue you are facing.

The `file_get_contents()` function will read the file as is (i.e., it will not remove the BOM or treat the file in any special way) and the `mysqli_multi_query()` function expects a simple stream of SQL code and is not able to detect and remove the BOM either.

The simplest solution is removing the BOM from the file. Seriously.

> setting the encoding of the file(in
>   notepade++) to UTF- WITHOUT BOM [...] garble[s] hebrew text thus I have
>   to keep the file as utf8.

Merely removing the BOM will not alter the file encoding at all. However, text editors that rely on finding a BOM may not be able to detect UTF-8 and will possibly interpret the file with some other (wrong) encoding, thus making the file look garbled. That's a visualization issue and shouldn't affect your code if you don't re-save the garbled file.